# Firebase function not getting called

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a likes value in the database and i want to change the value STATE when likes is more than 10.
Here is my database structure

```
"QUESTIONS" : {
"ENGLISH" : {
  "QUESTIONID" : 1
},
"SPANISH" : {
  "1" : {
    "ANSWER" : true,
    "LIKES" : 11,
    "MADEBY" : "lScayuKFOrOWyenYYxbL3lJ8Utt1",
    "QUESTION" : "djshsvs",
    "SPAM" : 1,
    "STATE" : "WAITING"
  },
  "2" : {
    "ANSWER" : true,
    "LIKES" : 2,
    "MADEBY" : "lScayuKFOrOWyenYYxbL3lJ8Utt1",
    "QUESTION" : "djdbdb",
    "STATE" : "WAITING"
  },
  "3" : {
    "ANSWER" : true,
    "MADEBY" : "lScayuKFOrOWyenYYxbL3lJ8Utt1",
    "MISPELLED" : 1,
    "QUESTION" : "fhki",
    "STATE" : "WAITING"
  },
  "4" : {
    "ANSWER" : true,
    "LIKES" : 1,
    "MADEBY" : "lScayuKFOrOWyenYYxbL3lJ8Utt1",
    "QUESTION" : "bkkki",
    "STATE" : "WAITING"
  },
  "QUESTIONID" : 4
}
```

},

My firebase function

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.newPost = functions.database
.ref('/QUESTIONS/SPANISH/{postID}'/"LIKES")
.onWrite(function(event) {

 const likes=event.data.value;
 const id=event.params.postID;

 if(likes>10){

    return event.data.ref.parent.child('STATE').set("ACEPTED");
 }
 return false;

});
```

The function is deployed correctly and all but when i increment the likes nothing happens, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You've included a photo of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Sorry about that, i have replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

Your string for the reference doesn't look right.  You have this:

```
'/QUESTIONS/SPANISH/{postID}'/"LIKES"
```

Shouldn't it be this instead?

```
'/QUESTIONS/SPANISH/{postID}/LIKES'
```

Comment: Even different: ES6 string templates are enclosed in back-ticks. So `\`/QUESTIONS/SPANISH/{postID}/LIKES\``.

Comment: Tried both, none of them works, is getting called but the state not getting setted.Any ideas about what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Except of changing reference string (as suggested above), try also changing this line:

```
const likes=event.data.value;
```

to this one:

```
 const likes=event.data.val();
```